# MS-Access: How to convert a text string in MM/DD/YYYY format to proper date in MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a MS-Access database table (with Candidate Data of a School) with few hundred records, with the Candidate's Date of Birth saved as a text string, STRICTLY in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

Now I want a query to retrieve the values,  while converting the text string values to Date type, so that it can be sorted (in desc or asc order of date, when needed) to find out the eldest candidate in the query result.

I discovered to my utter dispair that, the string "01/11/2003" is converted to date "01-Nov-2003" (It should have been 11-Jan-2003) but the string "11/15/2002" is converted to date "15-Nov-2002".

In the process, I tried the following strategies, all resulting in the same outcome:

1. Using custom VBA function ConvertMyStringToDateTime as suggested by Gord Thompson
2. `cdate([dob])` where dob is the field name that contains the Date of Birth as text String
3. `DateValue([dob])` where dob is the field name that contains the Date of Birth as text String
4. `Format([dob],"mm/dd/yyyy")` where dob is the field name that contains the Date of Birth as text String

How to force the conversion function to understand that I am always feeding the input text string as "mm/dd/yyyy" format?
[image]

Comment: Did you read this page?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/date-time/format-dates-as-u-s-dates-regardless-of-regional-settings

Comment: Thanks a ton. Although this did not directly resolve my problem, but helped me think in a different line. I went back to my local machine regional settings and reviewed the Date Tab. Set the Short Date format to MM/dd/yyyy format. Voila - that did it. Now the above picture is different. All text string dates in the dob column are getting interpreted correctly.

Comment: Your'e welcome :) Glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Use DateSerial:

```
TrueDoB: DateSerial(Mid([dob], 7, 4 ), Mid([dob], 1, 2), Mid([dob], 4, 2))
```

This snippet should teach you to store dates as Date, not as text.